# Is there a way to use the "read_csv" method to read the csv files in order they are listed in a directory?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, python-3.7

I am plotting plots on one figure using matplotlib from csv files however, I want the plots in order. I want to somehow use the read_csv method to read the csv files from a directory in the order they are listed in so that they are outputted in the same fashion.

I want the plots listed under each other the same way the csv files are listed in the directory.

Comment: Can you specify how those CSV files are ordered in the directory (e.g., by name or by modified date)? Files in a directory do not inherently have "order," but rather are listed according to user preference.

Comment: @FaustoMorales the file names are something like test3-1_ju23ng99 so I'm not sure how I can even order them.

Comment: Read all the file name in a pandas data frame and short it in alphabetical order. Once it is shorted, you should be able to read one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `os.listdir()` to get all the files in the folder and then sort them out in a certain way, for example by name(it would be enough using the python built in `sorted()` ). Instead if you want more fancy ordering you could retrieve both the name and last modified date and store them in a dictionary, order the keys and retrieve the values. So as @Fausto Morales said it all only depends on which order you would like them to be sorted.